# Possible to find a set of log-concave functions with log-concave sums?

Tags: convexity, convex-analysis, tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

While the set of log-convex functions is closed under addition, the set of log-concave functions is not. Yet if $f$ is log-concave, $\ln(k f) = \ln(k)+\ln(f)$, with $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$ constant, is concave. This suggests one can find a set of log-concave functions whose sums are still log-concave (possibly closed under addition).

> I am interested in the *concavity/convexity of $\ln(b+s)$, where $b,s$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$, increasing, positive, convex and log-concave*.

Example: I found $\ln(x^2+x^\beta)''<0, \forall x>0$ for $\beta<6$  (numerical result, perhaps not exact).

> Are there any results that could help delineate this set of functions? Perhaps for polynomials?

Some suggestions and more detailed description [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332369/67049)

The initial motivation for this problem comes from population dynamics.

Comment: I guess you are aware of log-concavity being closed under convolution, if not addition....

Comment: I've seen this - do you think I could use it?

Answer (score 5):

In fact $\ln(x^2 + x^\beta)$ is concave for $x > 0$ iff $3-2\sqrt{2} \le \beta \le 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}$. 
This comes from writing
$$ \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \ln(x^2 + x^\beta) = \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2 + x^\beta)^2} \left(-\beta x^{2\beta - 4} + (\beta^2 - 5 \beta + 2) x^{\beta - 2} -2\right)$$ 
and noting that the discriminant of $-\beta t^2 + (\beta^2 - 5 \beta + 2) t - 2$ with respect to $t$ is $(\beta^2 - 6 \beta + 1) (\beta - 2)^2$.

EDIT: Somewhat more generally, $\ln(x^\alpha + x^\beta)$ is concave for $x > 0$ iff
$\alpha=\beta$ or  $(\alpha-\beta)^2 - 2 (\alpha + \beta) + 1 \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks! The condition for log-concavity is very neat. Assuming $\beta > \alpha \geq 1$, $\gamma=\beta-\alpha$, the condition further simplify into $\gamma<1+2\sqrt{\alpha}$. In the general case, maybe I should seek similar relationships for elasticities ($\frac{x}{f}\frac{df}{dx}$). 

Writing down $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln(x^\alpha+x^\beta)$, I obtained
$\frac{x^{2\alpha-2}}{x^\alpha+x^\beta} (-\beta x^{(\beta-\alpha)2}+(\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha-\beta-2\alpha \beta)x^{(\beta-\alpha)}-\alpha)$
I suppose you used $t=x^{\beta-\alpha}$ and factored the discriminant as in the case $\alpha=2$?

Comment: Intermediate step: polynomial discriminant can be factored into $(\alpha-\beta)^2 (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 -2 \alpha \beta - 2 \alpha - 2 \beta +1)$.

Comment: Just checked: the criterion holds for sums of the form $\left(\frac{x}{A}\right)^\alpha + \left(\frac{x}{B}\right)^\beta$, with $A,B>0$ constants. 